# Nearby notification debugging

Tags: android, google-nearby

I have bought a beacon (#1) and registered it via the google beacon dashboard and added a nearby notification with a https web url. Using my android device running marshmallow I was regularly getting nearby notifications a week ago.

Since then the notifications during testing have reduced. And for the past two days I have had no notifications at all from the beacon. The beacon is 50cm from my android device and is discoverable from all 3rd part beacon scanners that I have installed. I have two other android devices which I use for test. They do not get nearby notifications recently either.

I've set up a fresh beacon (#2) and registered it via the google beacon dashboard and added another nearby notification but using a different https address ( https address #2 ). This gets notifications ok on all devices.

And so I take https address #2 and use it for the weburl on beacon #1 and now I get notifications from beacon #1 using https address #2

This leads me to believe that https address #1 is being filtered for some reason. But I need https address #1 to work to demonstrate to my potential customer.

My question is how can I debug why https address #1 does not work after a while. Or infact will all addresses stop working after a week or so. Is there any way to debug the black box between the beacon dashboard and my android device?

my follicle crop has been reduced significantly this week. Its a resource I am light on.

Answer (score 0):

I work on Nearby and there are two possibilities on why the notification for address #1 no longer shows up

1. There's notification back off policy in place where if the notification is shown multiple times and user did not interact with it, we'll back it off and eventually not show the notification.  This policy will reset if you go to the list view via (Settings -> Google -> Nearby)

   - Check list view ie. Nearby via (Settings -> Google -> Nearby) to see if you can still see the item there.
   - Note: we will make sure to update our documentation about this back off policy.
2. The url or its content may have triggered some filtering on our side. If you let me know what the url is then I can check to confirm.

Comment: I assume you mean settings -> google -> Nearby discoveries? I've been hitting refresh here a lot. Still, no notification though.
The url is https://r7-london.webserversystems.com/~peachyplacerob/

Comment: Going to look into this and get back to you.
Yes, I meant "settings -> google -> Nearby discoveries" for older version of Google Play Services,  new one is just settings -> google -> Nearby

Comment: We've made good progress on this, we've found some caching issue which will be fixed soon (within a week) and fetch failure which we aren't sure why yet except that it should be rare.  Will update again once we have more info by EOW or early next week.

Comment: I had tried some shortened urls also. Not sure if these are an issue.I'd post them but stack overflow wont allow them

Comment: Our server still have trouble fetching r7-london.webserversystems.com/~peachyplacerob and is still being investigated.  Is that your own web server?  It could be denying our fetch requests.

What did the shortener resolve to?  It matters what they resolved to.

Comment: The websites domain is http://www.peachy-place.com. Its hosted by site5 on their r7-london server.
Site5 offer a free https address ( which i'm using for this test ) but it needs to be used via the r7-london address. Hence the scary url.

The short urls resolved to https://r7-london.webserversystems.com/~peachyplacerob/


The tiny url is <https://tiny dot CC/r790ey>


To test the fetch deny i have set up another notification using a different address on the r7-london server. https://r7-london.webserversystems.com/~meangeni/  
This doesn't seem to be working either :(

Comment: I'm getting notifications from https://r7-london.webserversystems.com/~meangeni/ I dont know if this proves that site5 are denying the fetch. I'll speak with their support